# While Statement to keep checking the input files Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, while-loop

Pseudo Code:

`Open the file appointments.txt
    while more lines in input file, read line from file.
    Use split to extract the fields from line into fields array.`

What I have:

`File.open("appointments.txt")
while "some string" in appointments, read the file
fields = f.gets.chomp.split(',')`

I need a while statement to keep reading lines from the input file as long as there are more input lines in the file.

Comment: "I'm getting an error with my code." The best thing to do is include the error you're getting in your question. Can you edit your question to include the text? It would also help if you can include some sample input.

Comment: I'm getting an error somewhere else in my code, I'm confused on how to write the while statement.

Comment: Again, please, if you're getting "an error", tell people what it is. This is important. We're not psychic.

Comment: Why do you specifically need to use a while statement? Those are rarely, if ever needed in Ruby. Could you tell us what exactly is wrong with your current code?

Comment: There is no error with my code that is seen right now, I just need help witting a while statement to keep reading lines from the input file as long as there are more input lines in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [File#readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines).

```
File.open("appointments.txt", "r").readlines.map do |line|
  line.chomp
end
```

Comment: Can be minimized by using `map(&:chomp)` is equivalent.